# Flutter Firebase Cloud Messaging doesn't show badge number on Ios

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I think ios should to manage badge numbers automatic after get notifications. But it doesent't work for me and i can't find the solution. I request the permisson for badge too and i already get it, i see it on my settings. I use firebase cloud notification library only with notification tags. What could be the problem?

i tried to use:

```
"apns": {
   "payload": {
     "aps": {
       "badge": 5
     }
   }
 }
```

But doesen't work for me. If is it possible, i would like to manage it automatically.

Cloud messaging: `firebase_messaging: 6.0.16`

App delegate swift:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("key")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        
    }
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support

> The value of the badge on the home screen app icon.
> If not specified, the badge is not changed.
> If set to 0, the badge is removed.

I don't think that changing badge number automatically is possible for ios